# how can i fourier transform with negative frequency uncut in matlab?

Tags: matlab, fft

```
clear all;

Fs=100; %sampling rate

t=-10:(1/Fs):10;

for i=1:20*Fs+1

if -10<t(i) && t(i)<-9
x(i)= -1;

elseif -9<t(i) && t(i)<-8

x(i)=1;

elseif i>2*Fs+1

x(i)=x(i-(2*Fs));
```

shown above is the code for rectangular function with its domain [-10 10] and period of 2

and here is my positiveFFT function

```
function [X,freq]=positiveFFT(x,Fs)
N=length(x); %get the number of points
k=0:N-1;     %create a vector from 0 to N-1
T=N/Fs;      %get the frequency interval
freq=k/T;    %create the frequency range
X=fft(x)/N*2; % normalize the data

%only want the first half of the FFT, since it is redundant
cutOff = ceil(N/2); 

%take only the first half of the spectrum
X = X(1:cutOff);
freq = freq(1:cutOff);`
```

by doing this, i made a magnitude spectrum of this rectangular wave, but only when the frequency is positive.

How can i plot a whole magnitude spectrum that includes negative frequencies??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to obtain a vector of frequencies form -Fs/2 to Fs/2 and the corresponding magnitude of the spectrum. If so, you should use `fftshift`, for example:

```
N=length(x); %get the number of points
k=0:N-1;     %create a vector from 0 to N-1
T=N/Fs;      %get the frequency interval
freq=fftshift(k/T);    %create the frequency range
X=fftshift(fft(x))/N*2; % normalize the data
```